# How to change default permission of file

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, sudoers, passwd

I have 2 Debian machines.
======== Debain Machine  1===========

```
$ sudo install -m 0755 -d folder/kumar
$ echo "something" | sudo tee -a folder/dict/file
something
$ ls -lcrt folder/dict/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Oct 25 13:25 file
```

======== Debain Machine  2===========

```
$ sudo install -m 0755 -d folder/dict
$ echo "something" | sudo tee -a folder/dict/file
something
$ ls -lcrt folder/dict/
total 4
-rw------- 1 root root 6 Oct 25 13:03 file
```

How to achieve Debian Machine2 machine to behave like Debian machine1.

Comment: Is `umask` the same on both machines?

Comment: `umask -> 0022` , in both machine . just hint , `sudo su` in 2nd machine does ask me to change the root password. However, 1st machine does not. I have manually made , `$ sudo cat /etc/shadow | grep root ` == > r`oot:*:18911:0:99999:7::20089:` , in order to get rid of asking root password after entering `sudo su`.

Comment: Is `umask` the same after `sudo` on both machines? Run `sudo sh -c umask` on both and compare.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski in both cases it is : `sudo sh -c umask` `0077`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was there in /etc/login.confs ,
in Debian System 2, UMASK was set to 077
after updating /etc/login.confs with UMASK to 022, reboot the system it is giving expected output.

```
$ sudo install -m 0755 -d folder/kumar
$ echo "something" | sudo tee -a folder/dict/file
something
$ ls -lcrt folder/dict/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Oct 25 13:25 file
```